# How to cast a list to table name

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two hibernate classes TestAuthor and TestBook as shown below in the code. I inserted some records into the tables and they were inserted successfully. To make sure that the records were duly inserted, I used the following 
SQL commands

```
SELECT * from TESTAUTHOR;
SELECT * from afk_owner.TestBook;
```

I want now to display the contents of the table testbook using Hibernate command shown in the PrintAll section below. when I run the method PrintAll i receive an exception reads:

```
cannot be cast to msc.hibernate.persistence.TestBook
```

why I reeive this error and how to solve it.?

**PrintAll**:

```
private void printAll() {

    for (TestBook book : (List<TestBook>) HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * from afk_owner.testbook").list()) {

        System.out.println(book.getmISBN() + ", " + book.getmTitle() + " " + (book.getAuthor()));
    }
}
```

**TestAuthor**:

```
@Entity @Table(schema = "afk_owner", name = "testauthor")
public class TestAuthor {

@Id
@Column(name = "authorid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequencegen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequencegen", sequenceName = "afk_owner.testauthor_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer mAuthorID;

@Column(name = "FNAME")
private String mFName;

@Column(name = "LNAME")
private String mLName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<TestBook> books;

public Integer getmAuthorID() {
    return mAuthorID;
}

public void setmAuthorID(Integer mAuthorID) {
    this.mAuthorID = mAuthorID;
}

public String getmFName() {
    return mFName;
}

public void setmFName(String mFName) {
    this.mFName = mFName;
}

public String getmLName() {
    return mLName;
}

public void setmLName(String mLName) {
    this.mLName = mLName;
}

public TestAuthor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

**TestBook**:

```
@Entity @Table(schema = "afk_owner", name = "testbook")
public class TestBook {

@Id
@Column(name = "ISBN")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequencegen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequencegen", sequenceName = "afk_owner.testbook_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long mISBN;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "authorid")
private TestAuthor author;

@Column(name = "title")
private String mTitle;

public Long getmISBN() {
    return mISBN;
}

public void setmISBN(Long mISBN) {
    this.mISBN = mISBN;
}

public TestAuthor getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(TestAuthor author) {
    this.author = author;
}


public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public TestBook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It is not possibe using Hibernate API and native SQLs. There is no type controll so you have to cast.</strike> 
It is possible according to [Session Api docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html#createSQLQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) but it is ommited in [relevant part of documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) You will have to figure out how to use it to suit your needs. As those solutions are marked as deprecated, you should avoid using it at all. You should rather try to move to JPA and use Hibernate as its implementation.

If you would use HQL on the other hand, it could work. Query would be something like this:

```
Query<TestBook> query=session.createQuery("SELECT tb FROM TestBook tb WHERE tb.author.mAuthorID=:owner",TestBook.class);
query.setParameter("author",authorId);
List<TestBook> books=query.list();
```

You just have to adjust property names (tb, author, id property) etc to suit your needs, but you can get the idea how to use it.

Comment: can u please change your answer to match CreatSQLQuery?

Comment: @user2121 nope sorry, you have to try it yourself using provided links or switch to JPA or use HQL.